# Auto update file opened in vim editor when changed from external source

Tags: c++, vim

I just started using vim and I use

```
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
#endif
```

this to read my c++ programs output but in vim the output.txt file doesn't get updated automatically.

I know this because of all buffer issues, but is there a solution that can help to auto update the file.

Comment: the question is about vim, not about c++, right?

Comment: Something like... https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Have_Vim_check_automatically_if_the_file_has_changed_externally

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`'autoread'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27autoread%27):

> When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.

Simply execute `setlocal autoread` on the buffers you want Vim to watch, or add `set autoread` to your vimrc if you want that by default for all buffers.